# What is a proper resolution, and how many times of measurement needed for a credible experiments?

Tags: experimental-physics, measurements, statistics, experimental-technique

This question aims to understand a basic intuitive understanding and proper doing in practical situations for designing experiments.

1. Resolution

   Suppose there is an object large as a hand. What is enough resolution of scale on a ruler to measure this object?

   In a more practical situation, suppose a physical quantity can be measured as a peak in a graph. Let's say a gaussian peak. What is the possible resolution to be able to 'see' the peak? and what is a proper resolution for designing a credible experiment?
2. Amount of measurements

   Suppose that a coin has a chance of giving Heads 51% and 49% for Tails. How many times of measurement should be carried out to see this difference? I and not sure whether this question relates to uncertainty or not.

Comment: Your questions about deciding whether a Gaussian peak is signal or noise, or detecting an unfair coin, might fit better at [stats.se]. For an experimental-physics perspective, you might read the [Statistics chapter](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2021/reviews/rpp2021-rev-statistics.pdf) of the [Particle Data Group’s periodic review](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2021/).

Comment: @rob thanks for your editing and comment, but the question is not deciding a signal or noise. It is said that we already know that it is a peak having a width. It is in a situation that you want an experimental instrument for testing something which normally there should be a theoretical prediction. So that designing experiments will not take too much cost. So the instrument that you buy should be the one that can see the peak. But the question is how much of the resolution should be enough? How much of the resolution should be for the credit of the experiment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the size of a hand
2. the statistical uncertainty in counting experiments is poissonian, i.e. $\sqrt{n}$, so you need roughly $10^4$ throws to start seeing such a 1% difference ($10^2/10^4=1\%$)

Comment: thanks for your answer. It is on the point. But do you have any idea on the second question of 1.? Or any keywords that I can see further? for the 2. too.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you're asking in the second part of your first question. You may want to read up on "convolution"; E.g. if a quantity is a delta-peak, and your experiment has a finite (Gaussian) resolution, you measure the convolution of the two, which happens to be a Gaussian. Also, you may want to read up on "error propagation", which is how to calculate the final uncertainty on your measurement given uncertainties in your apparatus.